# How can I go to end in word, using vba from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, selection

In my vba code I need to go to the end of the word document.
The vba is written and executed from Excel. 
The statement : Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove " will not run.
Can anyone explain where I do the mistyping.

I have tried to use the statement in other vba codes, but without success.

```
Sub InsertFromFilesTestEnd()


Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document


    Set wrdApp = New Word.Application
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("c:\users\peter\documents\direkte 0302 1650.docm")
        wrdApp.Visible = True
        wrdApp.Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
End Sub
```

Hopefully you can guide me to the end of my document. When so, I am sure I can use "selection" to move around in the document.

Comment: What does "Will not run" mean? The line in the script executes but your cursor isn't at the end of the document? Or you get an error when that line is executed?

Comment: The code stops, with a runtime error 438. Object dosn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `Selection` isn't qualified to which application's `Selection` you are wanting. As such, it's using the default for Excel VBA, which would be the Excel Application in which the VBA was launched. Implicitly you are saying:

```
Application.Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
```

The error is because Excel's `Application.Selection` object doesn't have an `EndKey` method and so VBA has no idea what you are trying to do here.

Instead you want to qualify that `Selection` with the instance of the `Word.Application` object you are already working with:

```
wrdApp.Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Selections in cases like this is quite unnecessary. Aside from being inefficient, it's also prone to producing a lot of screen flicker. Try, for example:

```
Sub InsertFromFilesTestEnd()
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Set wrdApp = New Word.Application
With wrdApp
    .Visible = True
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wrdDoc = .Documents.Open("c:\users\peter\documents\direkte 0302 1650.docm")
    With wdrDoc
        .Range.Characters.Last.InsertFile FileName:="MyFileName", Range:="", _
            ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
    End With
    .Activate
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```